# jQuery ASP.net webservice consumption

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, web-services, asmx

I have been looking on how to consume a webmethod using the $.ajax call using this code below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
```

However when I tried to change the type from "POST" to "GET", the call didn't go through. Can someone please point out a reason why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By degault `GET` requests are disabled for ASP.Net AJAX Web services, [ScottGu has an excellent blog entry on this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx), including how to bypass that security if that's what you're after.

Here's an example fix, by setting [`UseHttpGet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget.aspx) on the [`ScriptMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298830.aspx):

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)] 
public string HelloWorld() 
{
  return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Adding the UseHttpGet did get the call through...but then being less secure... I will use POST method instead it doesn't make difference to me which one I will be using. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

As Nick wrote you can use `ScriptMethodAttribute` or you can enable `GET` request processing in web.config:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking the server side code to see where it pulls values from? it may not respond depending on the method used.

also an aside: if you are retrieving data from a web service, the logically correct method is usually GET.